# macOS: Disconnect Wi-Fi without turning it off

Tags: macos, mac, network, wifi, airdrop

How can I disconnect from Wi-Fi on Mac without turning it off? I do not want to connect via Wi-Fi on my Mac as I am connected via LAN. But when I turn Wi-Fi off, I also lose the ability to use services dependant on Wi-Fi availability such as AirDrop.

I was able to achieve it currently by forgetting available access points, and leaving the Wi-Fi on, but I have to re-join the access point by entering its password again if needed, which is not convenient.

Can I disconnect from Wi-Fi on my Mac and also leave it on? I am able to do the same on an iPhone by tapping Wi-Fi icon in Control Centre. It disconnect from Wi-Fi while leaving the Wi-Fi and thus I am able to use services such as AirDrop.

I cannot appear to do it on my Mac. I have looked in Network System Preference pane and also under the Wi-Fi Menu bar icon, but I cannot find any option.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can press and hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> key when clicking on the Wi-Fi icon in the menu bar. This way, you'll be presented with the extended menu of options and there find the option to disconnect from the currently connected access point without forgetting it or turning off the Wi-Fi.

#### Clicking on Wi-Fi menu bar icon normally

[image: macOS Wi-Fi menu options]

#### Clicking on Wi-Fi menu bar icon while pressing and holding down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key

[image: macOS Wi-Fi menu extended options]

Other services dependant on Wi-Fi availability such as AirDrop would continue to work.

**P.S.**: Other access points and extended network information blurred.

Answer (score 9):

If the goal is simply to ensure that you use the LAN when available, and wifi otherwise, then you don't need to disconnect the wifi at all.

Simply drag the Ethernet entry *above* the Wi-Fi entry in the Network pane of System Preferences, and it'll use the former when available.  The wifi can remain connected, but it'll only be used for data when the LAN is disconnected.